# Task restart immediately after completion while parallel processing

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, console-application, task-parallel-library

I have to restart all task immediately after completion of the same. Please have a look into my program below;

```
class Program
    {
         static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            int _count = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                await ProcessTasksAsync();
                Console.Write("----Restart Tasks----" + (_count++).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        }

        static async Task ProcessTasksAsync()
        {
            Task<int> taskA = LongTaskA(10);
            Task<int> taskB = MediumTaskB(10);
            Task<int> taskC = ImmediateTaskC(10);

            var tasks = new[] { taskA, taskB, taskC };

            var processingTasks = tasks.Select(AwaitAndProcessAsync).ToList();
            await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
        }

        static async Task AwaitAndProcessAsync(Task<int> task)
        {
            var result = await task;
            Console.WriteLine("Return Result: " + result);
        }

        static async Task<int> LongTaskA(int _processingCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _processingCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("LongTaskA:{0}", i.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
                await Task.Delay(7000);
            }
            return 1;
        }

        static async Task<int> MediumTaskB(int _processingCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _processingCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("MediumTaskB:{0}", i.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
            return 2;
        }

        static async Task<int> ImmediateTaskC(int _processingCount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _processingCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("ImmediateTaskC:{0}", i.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            return 3;
        }

    }
```

The Tasks A, B & C runs parallelly. But, even though the completion of certain task doesn't get restart after completion of the same. As i used "Whenall" it waits to complete the other task.

I want to restart each task after completion of the same. How can i achieve that?

Thanks,
Shenu

Comment: You should call `Task.Run()` containing a loop for each task you want to have it's own "cycle"

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it would be great if you could elaborate your comment a little more. Thanks

Comment: Look at the answer of Stephen;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program currently runs the three tasks concurrently, (asynchronously) waits for them all to complete, and then does that in a loop.

If you want to run *each task* in a loop, then you just move the loop:

```
static async Task ProcessTasksAsync()
{
  Task<int> taskA = LoopA(10);
  Task<int> taskB = LoopB(10);
  Task<int> taskC = LoopC(10);

  await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC);
}

static async Task LoopA()
{
  while (true)
    await AwaitAndProcessAsync(LongTaskA(10));
}

static async Task LoopB()
{
  while (true)
    await AwaitAndProcessAsync(MediumTaskB(10));
}

static async Task LoopC()
{
  while (true)
    await AwaitAndProcessAsync(ImmediateTaskC(10));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. Its working as expected. Cheers!